# dropdownlist unable to find in rowupdating event

Tags: drop-down-menu, templatefield

I use TemplateField to create dropdownlist in 2nd column when in edit mode. but it cannot be find cell(1).control(0) when in RowUpdating event, only the cell(0) TextBox can be find. It shows the argument out of range exception. Anyone also face the same issue？

```
TemplateColumn = New TemplateField
TemplateColumn.ShowHeader = True
TemplateHeaderTxt = dicColumnMap(gDataTable.Columns.Item(i).Caption)
TemplateDataField = gDataTable.Columns.Item(i).Caption
TemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate = New GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType.Header, TemplateHeaderTxt, "", "")
TemplateColumn.ItemTemplate = New GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, TemplateDataField, TemplateDataField, "Label")
TemplateColumn.EditItemTemplate = New GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, TemplateDataField, TemplateDataField, "DropDowmList", sqlConn)

Account_GridView.DataSource = gDataTable
Account_GridView.DataBind()


Private Sub Account_GridView_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles Account_GridView.RowUpdating
        Dim row = Account_GridView.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        Dim accountdate, payflow, member, typename, subtype, price, exchangeRate, comment, groupname, ID As String

        Dim cnt = row.Cells.Count

        accountdate = CType(row.Cells(0).Controls(0), TextBox).Text        
        payflow = CType(row.Cells(1).Controls(0), DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value
End Sub
```

I tried row.Cells(1).HasControls, but it shows false, it is obvious no object in 2nd column, it is so weird